# Add consume filter to batch consumer

Tags: c#, batch-processing, masstransit

I code service with MassTransit and RabbitMQ.

I have endpoint configuration with few filters:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("BillingTransaction",
   e =>
        {
          e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(defaultRetryCount, defaultRetryPeriod));
          e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(CacheTransactionFilter<>), context);
          e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(TransactionValidationFilter<>), context);
          e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(TransactionDispatchingFilter<>), context);
          e.ConfigureConsumer<TransactionEventConsumer>(context);
          EndpointConvention.Map<ITransactionEvent>(e.InputAddress);
        });
```

And i have TransactionEventConsumer what consume ITransactionEvent.
For now i recieve ITransactionEvent and filtering it by Filters.

But i need change TransactionEventConsumer from `IFilter<ConsumeContext<ITransactionEvent>>` to `IFilter<ConsumeContext<Batch<ITransactionEvent>>>` and still filtering ITranscationEvent by one, not by batch.

As i know, i can use `.UseFilter` in RecieveEndpoint configuration method, but with it i can't access DI container with service's. `context.GetPayload<IServiceProvider>()` always return null.

How can i use filter for one ITransactionEvent and then consume thay by batch consumer?